# Keeping ChildWindow on Top

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a MainWindow and ChildWindow. When MainWindow is active, have focus on it or looses its focus, I'm bringing up ChildWindow to the top.
Now when I'm opening up a popup from the MainWindow, ChildWindow goes behind MainWindow. I'd like to keep ChildWindow on the top in that case as well.
Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Comment: Unless the childwindow view was not overlapping with the mainwindow, it is not possible to keep childwindow visible.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#zorder

Have a look at the description of the Z order. This determines the order in which windows are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify it's Owner window.

For example:

```
ChildWindow childWindow = new ChildWindow();
childWindow.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
childWindow.ShowDialog();
```